# kafka-console-consumer with Kerberos and --zookeeper parameter throws BrokerEndPointNotAvailableException

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, kafka-consumer-api, jaas, sasl

I can't consume messages from Kafka with `kafka-console-consumer` and `--zookeeper` parameter, in a Kerberized Hadoop cluster.

Here is my test environment :

- Cloudera CDH 5.7.0
- Kafka 0.10.1.0

I'm working on a single-node cluster (hostname = `quickstart.cloudera`) for testing purposes. I produce messages with `kafka-console-producer`.

For consumers, I am using these configuration files :

`jaas.conf` :

```
KafkaClient {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=true
keyTab="/home/simpleuser/simpleuser.keytab"
principal="simpleuser@CLOUDERA";
};
```

`client.properties` :

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
```

With those files, I am able to receive messages when using `--new-consumer` and `--bootstrap-server` :

```
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/simpleuser/jaas.conf"
kafka-console-consumer \
    --new-consumer \
    --topic test-kafka \
    --bootstrap-server quickstart.cloudera:9092 \
    --consumer.config client.properties
```

With `--zookeeper` option, I had to update the JAAS config file and added a `Client` section for Zookeeper (otherwise, it throws a warning : `No JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified JAAS configuration file`) :

`jaas_with_zk.conf` :

```
KafkaClient {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=true
keyTab="/home/simpleuser/simpleuser.keytab"
principal="simpleuser@CLOUDERA";
};

Client {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=true
keyTab="/home/simpleuser/simpleuser.keytab"
principal="simpleuser@CLOUDERA";
};
```

With this file, the command :

```
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/simpleuser/jaas_with_zk.conf"
kafka-console-consumer \
    --topic test-kafka \
    --zookeeper quickstart.cloudera:2181 \
    --consumer.config client.properties
```

throws an exception (`BrokerEndPointNotAvailableException`) :

```
WARN Property sasl.kerberos.service.name is not valid (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
WARN Property security.protocol is not valid (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
WARN [console-consumer-40368_quickstart.cloudera-1514305767949-b4724797-leader-finder-thread], Failed to find leader for Set([test-kafka,0]) (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread)
kafka.common.BrokerEndPointNotAvailableException: End point with security protocol PLAINTEXT not found for broker 35
        at kafka.cluster.Broker$$anonfun$5.apply(Broker.scala:131)
        at kafka.cluster.Broker$$anonfun$5.apply(Broker.scala:131)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
        at kafka.cluster.Broker.getBrokerEndPoint(Broker.scala:130)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$$anonfun$getAllBrokerEndPointsForChannel$1.apply(ZkUtils.scala:221)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$$anonfun$getAllBrokerEndPointsForChannel$1.apply(ZkUtils.scala:221)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.getAllBrokerEndPointsForChannel(ZkUtils.scala:221)
        at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:65)
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
```

`35` is the value for the `broker.id` specified in the `kafka.properties`. I don't understand why the stack trace is talking about `PLAINTEXT` security protocol, because in the `kafka.properties` file, there is no such information about `PLAINTEXT`, only `SASL_PLAINTEXT` :

```
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://quickstart.cloudera:9092
```

And in `client.properties`, I have :

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

Moreover, `sasl.kerberos.service.name` and `security.protocol` seems to be unused (first two lines of the stacktrace). Passing `--security-protocol PLAINTEXTSASL` (as suggested by [this thread](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/59219/kafka-console-consumer-not-reading-messages.html)) does not work (`security-protocol is not a recognized option`).

For information, here is the `kafka.properties` used (I removed properties that seems unrelated to my problem) :

```
authenticate.zookeeper.connection=true
broker.id=35
kerberos.auth.enable=true
port=9092
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
unclean.leader.election.enable=false
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=6000
broker.id.generation.enable=false
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://quickstart.cloudera:9092
```

Comment: I strongly recommend splitting the question into at least 2 different questions with just one with Spark Streaming as the client to consume messages from a kerberized Kafka broker. Currently the question is too broad.

Comment: I thought it was a good idea to ask the questions together, because the issues seems related. But you're right, it's a broad question, so I just created a new question, focusing only on Spark Streaming application in YARN mode : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977075/consuming-kafka-messages-from-a-spark-streaming-application-in-a-kerberized-hado

Comment: Thanks. Remove the part of the question here related to Spark Streaming then.

Comment: I have just updated this question and only kept the `kafka-console-consumer` issue. @JacekLaskowski Could you please remove the duplicate mark ? Thanks for the advice, the questions are much more clearer now